# Angular5 LandingPage without /home url

Tags: angular

I would like my landing page URL to be myapp.com.

Currently, inside src/index.html I have

```
<head>
  <base href="/">
</head>
```

In app.component.html I have

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

In app.module.ts I have

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
{path: 'home', component: HomeComponent},
{path: '', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full'}
];
```

I don't want to redirect myapp.com to myapp.com/home, I want myapp.com to show my landing page and I would like myapp.com/feature to show another page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not want myapp.com to redirect to nyapp.com/home why are you telling it to do so?

get rid of this line:

```
{path: '', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full'}
```

So your routes would look like this:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {path: '', component: HomeComponent},
  {path: 'feature', component: FeatureComponent}
];
```

Comment: He needs: {path: '', component: HomeComponent}

Comment: Oh so he wants HomeComponent to be his landing page

Answer (score 1):

Changing your routing to have the route to your component be: `{path: '', component: HomeComponent, pathMatch: 'full'}` and get rid of the route performing a redirect should do just that.